# IIS6 and PHP pages (not being served)

Tags: apache-2.2, iis-6

I used this link: http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/php2003/installer.asp

to integrate PHP with IIS. Followed to a "T"

When I try to hit a directory with index.php, I get prompted to open or save rather than the page being served. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This means that IIS is finding your PHP files ok, but it doesn't know how to process them.  The "installer" apparently has not set up the ISAPI filter or an extension mapping within the web site entries.  The same web site references [manual installation instructions](http://www.simongibson.com/intranet/php2003/default.asp) which include those steps.  If you follow those instructions it will likely solve the problem you're experiencing.  Note that the extension or ISAPI mapping within the web site properties is different from the allowed "web service extensions".  Both are required but the "installer" instructions only have you add one of them.